# totalTime [Leaflet Routing Machine]

Tags: javascript, routes, leaflet

I'm actually working for a school project with the Leaflet Routing Machine and having issue withe the totalTime method.

```
    var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('', {
    attribution: ''
}).addTo(map);

L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
        L.latLng(45.7979, 4.7178),
        L.latLng(45.5221, 4.8101),
        L.latLng(45.42, 4.35)
    ],
    routeWhileDragging: true,
    language: 'fr'
}).addTo(map);

L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
        L.latLng(44.7979, 4.7178),
        L.latLng(45.42, 4.35)
    ],
    routeWhileDragging: true,
    language: 'fr'
}).addTo(map);

window.alert(routes[0].summary.totalTime());
```

But JS console is telling me that routes[] isn't defined.

Is there anything wrong ? Should we use something else than routes[] ?

Comment: You, uh, haven't defined `routes` anywhere in this code.

Comment: Sure, but i would like too call the method `totalTime`. http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#irouter
I've found this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570980/getting-distance-between-2-markers
So i tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the fact that the 'routesfound' event is not used on the Routing control. Try to add the event and handle the distance and time results inside the handler

```
routeCtr.addTo(map).on('routesfound', function (e) {
        distance = e.routes[0].summary.totalDistance;
        min = e.routes[0].summary.totalTime;
};
```

Try it.